# How to create version in Jira properly?

Tags: tfs, jira

How do you version in JIRA when your versions are like `4.8.{TFSBuild}.{TeamCity.Build}`?
Do I simply create a 4.8 Version in Jira?
However what would I set the release date to?

The problem is that our versions are dynamically and created based on the build# from tfs and the Team City build#.
What is now the best way for me to create versions in Jira?
Only the Major. Minor is hardcoded for now and for every few bug fixes we upload the release to the live server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jira versions are primarily a planning tool (especially if you use Greenhopper aka Agile, where you can have a version hierarchy).
So that's different from a build. It may take a thousand builds to achieve the functionality planned for a "FixFor" version.

On the other hand, "Affects" versions are used to track in which build a particular bug was found. So it'll pay to rename the "current version" (when you mark it as Released) to the actual build, as Hugo suggests. And cleanup/close/move any outstanding issues at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to name the upcoming version that doesn't have a fixed name yet something like "Next release".

When you actually do release that version then you can change the version name in Jira to reflect the correct name.

Comment: I'm fighting the same problem as vikasde, and I think this approach is best.  Something like 4.8-dev until you release something to your customers.  You could use a custom field to track the specific development build if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Jira For Project Management - Creating Versions**

We use Jira for project management of daily task assignment and we like to have versions either by week or by month. This lets us assign work for a week and is very helpful with the Greenhopper plug in. Basically, you:

1. Open the project from "Projects"
2. On left side, click on "Versions"

We have version 4.4 so might be slightly different other Jira versions.